# CodePipeline - Encountered unsupported property configuration

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

When deploying this CloudFormation template through SLS I'm getting a cryptic error message with no more information from CloudFormation Events:

```yaml
  FrontendPipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      Name: FrontendPipeline-${opt:stage, 'dev'}
      RoleArn: !GetAtt FrontendCodePipeLineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref FrontendPipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - Name: FrontendSource
          Actions:
            - Name: FrontendSourceAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeCommit
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                BranchName: "dev"
                OutputArtifactFormat: CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF
                RepositoryName: !GetAtt RepoFrontend.Name
              OutputArtifacts:
                - name: Frontend-${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: FrontendBuildAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: 1
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: FrontendSource
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: FrontendBuild
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref FrontendCodeBuild
```

The error is:

```
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

    An error occurred: CodePipeline - Encountered unsupported property configuration.
```

Which is ths unsuported property?

Comment: Do the [CloudWatch Logs](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home#logsV2:log-groups) have any extra info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few potential problems with your template:

- You use `configuration` in the first stage instead of `Configuration` like you do in the second
- You use `outputArtifacts` in the first stage instead of `OutputArtifacts` like you do in the second

Comment: name was on lowercase aswell